# Running filemaker pro 6 on an Intel-based Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, powerpc, macos

Recently moved my wife's content and settings from a white Macbook to an Intel-based Macbook pro.
So when I went to open her contacts database created in Filemaker Pro 6, no dice, since that is a PowerPC-based program.
And if I try using the later-version trial I got from Filemaker, it's Catch 22 time all over again, since I cannot import the file without having a working version of Filemaker Pro 6.

Comment: I assume that the primary goal is recovery of data, not necessarily getting v6 to run. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10571/kw/migrating%20from%20filemaker%20pro%206/session/L3RpbWUvMTM2MTY5NDczNy9zaWQvbnRtNWhFamw=) in the Filemaker support database, you should be able to recover your data by converting the v6 database with [FileMaker Pro 11](http://fmdl.filemaker.com/TBUB/eleven/fmp_trial_fm_11.0.4.401b.dmg) first.

Answer (score 0):

Filemaker 6 version files will only work on 6.

Filemaker 7 would convert the file forward (but it wouldn't be reverse-compatible to a version 6 app) (fmp7)

additionally, the next format is version 12 (.fp12)

You'll need to either have a Mac running 10.6, or a version 7 of Filemaker (which will run on any OSX from 10.4 up to 10.11), OR a version 12, on (10.9-10.11)